# Position of window.onload in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=myFunction;
</script>
```

Is there any difference in using the above snippet in the `<head></head>` tag and just before
`</body>` tag, as I would like to call my function after the page loads.

Comment: "in tag and just before tag" - what do you mean by this? "tag" would refer to?

Comment: @Prabhavith what do you mean by (in tag and just before tag)

Comment: Also, you want to call your script after all images and external resources has loaded? Or just after the HTML is ready - in which you want to use the `DOMContentLoaded` instead.

Comment: i guess he thinks about `<body onload="...">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding to `window.onload` will always run your function when the `load` event fires. This only fires after everything in the page has finished loading, including images etc. If you want to run your function when the DOM has finished loading but before everything else then you can bind to the `DOMContentLoaded` event or use a library like jQuery (e.g. `$(function(){ myFunction() });`).

The benefit about putting your function at the end of your `<body>` is that theoretically this means that the rest of your content has already loaded and you don’t need to bind your function to a `load` event. This sometimes works, but depends on the situation.

Comment: what happens when the control finds window.onload at the beginning of the script

Comment: A function bound to `window.onload` found anywhere in the initial loading period will be fired after the content has finished loading, regardless of where that binding happens (either in `<head>` or `<body>`).

Answer (score 4):

basically there's no pratical difference, but I recommend

1. to place that code at the bottom, since you need to use a script (blocking-rendering tag) it's better put it at the end of the document.
2. to avoid a destructive assignments like that: writing `window.onload=myFunction` you destroy other previous assignments to `window.onload` event (if any) so it's better something like

   ```
   (function() {
      var previousOnLoadIfAny = window.onload;
      window.onload = function() {  
         if (typeof previousOnLoadIfAny === 'function') {
            previousOnLoadIfAny();
         }
         yourfunction();
      }
   }());
   ```

Answer (score 1):

No, where you place that will not matter - anywhere in the document and it will trigger when the document and all external resources (images, scripts etc) has loaded.

Because `onload` triggers after all external resources one often want to use `DOMContentLoaded` instead which triggers when the HTML DOM is ready. Which will make for a page that is more responsive.